# Backup remote SQL Server database to local

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to backup a live database to my computer and I can't find the option to do it. I'm connecting to it using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2. I'm a MySQL monkey, so I'm used to being able to backup to `.sql` files and move them around.

Anyone have any idea how I can create a file backup of the database? I've found the backup option which only backs up on the server, or the export, which seems to only allow a single table, or code an SQL query, which I'm not too sure on, short of putting in something like `SHOW TABLES;`

Anyone have any ideas? I'm limited to readonly access for various reasons, nothing bad, promise!

Comment: I don't think you can backup to client. And that would be a huge security break.

Comment: @iDevlop, I don't think is such a huge security risk; if you can query it you can copy it. The only thing is that you don't automate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will only be able to backup the database to a location the service account for SQL has access to. If you have access to a central share on the server/network that you can access and the service can, you might backup to that location and then browse from your computer to pull it down.

If you are just wanting the database structure you could script the database out to a file. This would let you save it locally. If you also want the data though doing a full backup is the quickest way I know of.

**EDIT**

I would use the T-SQL `BACKUP` comand and include `WITH COPY_ONLY` to backup the database, since you stated this is a "live" database. If a scheduled job is performing backups against the database and you break in to do an additional one you will effect the backup recovery chain of the database. Using the `COPY_ONLY` will allow you to get a backup of the database without requiring it in the event of a recovery need.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the backup. I've taken a copy of the schema and dumped some tables to `csv` to have same sample data. Then I can recreate it locally and play about.

Answer (score 1):

You can enter a valid UNC path in the Backup option.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create sql dumps with Management Studio.

Right-click the database and select Tasks - Generate Scripts. This will open a wizard that allows you to select what the dump should include (e.g. tables, indices, views, ...).

Make sure you set "Script Data" to true if you want your dump to include inserts.